# Ubuntu is slower after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 and for some reason, the system is slower. It takes more time to open files, open the screen with applications, even just dragging the mouse to select more files on screen is slower. It's maybe just a second but it is noticeable and I'd like to know why is it happening because on 18.10 everything was fine.

CPU is not working extra harder than usually; 8gb RAM, AMD A12-9720 and AMD Radeon r7... not the fastest computer in the universe but still, is it possible that my PC just can't handle Ubuntu?

```
dmesg|grep -i error:
```

[image: prt sc of error code]

```
glxinfo -B:
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
    Device: AMD Radeon R7 Graphics (CARRIZO, DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-13-generic, LLVM 8.0.0) (0x9874)
    Version: 19.0.2
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 512MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 145 MB, largest block: 145 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 3038 MB, largest block: 3038 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 145 MB, largest block: 145 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 3038 MB, largest block: 3038 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 145 MB, largest block: 145 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 3038 MB, largest block: 3038 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 512 MB
    Total available memory: 3584 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 145 MB
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R7 Graphics (CARRIZO, DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-13-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Check for BIOS updates. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to support.hp.com to check for a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You machine has more than enough resources to run Ubuntu 19.04 smoothly.

My guess is that something must have been disabled during the upgrade, maybe the AMD official drivers?

If you go to Software Sources in the additional drivers tab, it should show you if there is anything that needs installing.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no software I should install (according to the additional drivers tab).

Comment: Can you post the result of the following command?
dmesg|grep -i error

Comment: I edited the question with a link to the code. ... I just remembered that the upgrade got stuck on updating linux kernel (I read that it happens), I eventually interrupted the upgrade by forcing PC to shut down because it was completely unresponsive for a long time. That gave me broken system with only parts of it functioning - after login I saw just a black screen, empty dock and date and time on top. I somehow manage to trigger a kind of terminal screen when booting and from there I resumed the upgrade. Everything seemed fine so I didn't think much about it.

Comment: You mention that your CPU is not working extra hard so I'm thinking that it might be your graphical acceleration that doesn't work and gives you that sense of sluggishness. Could you try to install the `meta-utils` package and run `glxinfo -B` ?

Comment: I think you were right. The problem was probably in graphic memory, or the lack of it. But after restart and some tweaking it is fine now.